# Error:(31, 32) error: incompatible types: FragmentOne cannot be converted to Context

Tags: java, android

Am trying to play sounds so I can make a soundboard app, have decided to make it a sliding app to change between activities but it won't let me add the sound pool.
Error is happening between the two **. Please help me, am new to coding.

```
package com.jonatboard.jonat.htssoundboard;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.media.AudioManager;






public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {


SoundPool Clubb1;
    int clubb1Id;






    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Clubb1 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 1);
        clubb1Id = Clubb1.load**(this, R.raw.clubb1,1)**;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one_layout, container, false);

    }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `getActivity()` to retrieve the activity's context where `FragmentOne` is inflated.

Change

```
clubb1Id = Clubb1.load(this, R.raw.clubb1,1);
```

with

```
clubb1Id = Clubb1.load(getActivity(), R.raw.clubb1,1);
```